# Top bar like unity

Tags: unity, gnome, top-bar

When are you will make top bar like unity? A lot of space is occupied by these buttons. [Gnome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OZu8.png), [Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux54C.png).

Answer (score 1):

You can move the maximized windows title and buttons on the top bar in Gnome Shell by using the [Unite](https://github.com/hardpixel/unite-shell) extension.

[image]

This extension can also move the notifications and the date/time to the right like in Unity, focus new windows and more. Image from [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/04/make-gnome-shell-more-like-unity-with.html).

Comment: This extension has bugs, double buttons. And it does not move to the top bar of the application control button. (file edit selection view.. )

Comment: You may be using a different extension too because there are no double buttons for me. Also see the screenshot... As for the second part, I didn't understand what you're saying.